# Fill HTML content to Docx template

Tags: java, node.js, ruby, templates, docx

I'm working on a project which aims to gather survey from users and fill them into our Word template.

The user input is in HTML format with inline style and inline images ( tag with base64 or image link source), and I want to fill them into our existing survey template which is in Docx format.

I have tried multiples library including:

- ruby/sablon
- java/docx4j
- nodejs/docxtemplater (raw xml feature)

But none of them seems to match with what I need (maybe I missed it?).

Is there any way to achieve what I want to do? I'm open to any kind of tools or programming languages.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

docx4j's content control data binding can bind escaped XHTML; it uses docx4j-ImportXHTML to convert the escaped XHTML to real docx content.  You can Google 'OpenDope' for more.